# Fan control on Acer Aspire One D255 netbook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, acer, fan

I have Ubuntu netbook edition on my Acer Aspire One D255 netbook and I notice that I always hear the fan working at 100% despite the actual temperature.

I run the sensors command its only at 13c, theres no reason why the fan needs to be running this hard at that temp.

```
root@adam-netbook:~# sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +13.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

I'm guessing I may need some drivers in order to interact with the fan? Does anyone have any experience with this?

It also seems that "sensors" may not be all that accurate, the temperature never seems to fluctuate.

Answer (score 2):

I had a dell laptop that was doing the same thing but in my case it was just clogged up heat sinks, after maintenance (cleaning the heat sinks) everything went back to normal, I think your case is different based on what you say here so I am suggesting that you look at this site and see if anything there can help you. http://www.netbooktech.com/2008/09/17/fix-the-acer-aspire-one-noisy-fan-for-both-windows-and-linux/

They link to software that can control the fan, someone even suggests opening the device and oil the fan. looks like you have a cheap fan problem rather than dirty heat sink problem.